# AJAX returns only last array item

Tags: javascript, php

I want to create async AJAX query to check server status when web page finish loading. Unfortunately when it comes to data display from processed PHP, I receive only single value.

JS:

```
<script>

  window.onload = function() {
      test();
    };

  function test()
  {
      var h = [];

      $(".hash td").each(function(){

        var hash = $(this).closest('#h').text();

        if (hash) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'stat.php',
                method: 'POST',
                async: true,
                data: {hs: JSON.stringify(hash)},
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.result').replaceWith(data);
                }
            });
        }
      });
    }
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

require_once ('inc/config.php');
require_once ('inc/libs/functions.php');

if (isset($_POST['hs'])) {

  $hash = json_decode($_POST['hs']);

  serverstatus($hash);
}

function serverstatus($hash) {

    $address = DB::queryFirstRow("SELECT address,hash FROM servers WHERE hash=%s", $hash);

    $address_exploded = explode(":", $address['address']);
    $ip = $address_exploded[0];
    $port = $address_exploded[1];

    $status = isServerOnline($ip,$port);

    if ($status) {
      $s = "Online $ip";
    } else {
      $s = "Offline";
    }
    echo $s;
}

?>
```

I embed result from PHP to a table row. I see that AJAX iterating over the array, but all rows receive same value (last checked element in array).

Comment: You keep overwriting the same HTML element(s). `$('.result').replaceWith(data);`

Comment: I arrived the same conclusion @JonStirling

Comment: Just as a side note: if you think that the error lies within the generation of data, you should check that. For AJAX calls, there are great tools in your browser's network console that can help you to see what exactly that AJAX calls return

Comment: With what you appear to be returning, I'd expect only the **first** to end up in the DOM, not only the **last**, since you're replacing an element with plain text (which won't, then, have the class anymore)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.result')` matches **all** elements with the class `result`. `replaceWith` will then replace each of them with the content you provide.

If you want to only affect the `.result` element within some structure (perhaps the same row?), you need to use `find` or similar:

```
function test()
{
    var h = [];

    $(".hash td").each(function(){
        var td = $(this);                              // <====
        var hash = td.closest('#h').text();
        var result = td.closest("tr").find(".result"); // <====

        if (hash) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'stat.php',
                method: 'POST',
                async: true,
                data: {hs: JSON.stringify(hash)},
                success: function(data) {
                    result.replaceWith(data);          // <====
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Obviously the

```
var result = td.closest("tr").find(".result"); // <====
```

...will need to be tweaked to be what you really want it to be, but that's the idea.

---

This line in your question suggests an anti-pattern:

```
var hash = $(this).closest('#h').text();
```

`id` values **must** be unique in the document, so you should never need to find the one "closest" to any given element. If you have more than one `id="h"` element in the DOM, change it to use a `class` or `data-*` attribute instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for help. My final, obviously very dirty but working code:

```
function testServerPage()
{
    var h = [];

    $(".hash li").each(function(){

      var hash = $(this).closest('#h').text();

      if (hash) {
          $.ajax({
              url: 'stat.php',
              method: 'POST',
              //async: true,
              data: {hs: JSON.stringify(hash)},
              success: function(data) {
                  $('#' + hash).replaceWith(data);
              }
          });
      }
    });
    return false;
}
```

I just added dynamic variable to element:

```
success: function(data) {
                      $('#' + hash).replaceWith(data);
                  }
```